# device-wise css media query not working properly

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have 5 list-items in an unordered list.

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li>First item</li>
   <li>Second item</li>
   <li>THird item</li>
   <li>Fourth item</li>
   <li>Fifth item</li>
</ul>
<ul class="dd-menu">
   <li>First item</li>
   <li>Second item</li>
   <li>THird item</li>
   <li>Fourth item</li>
   <li>Fifth item</li>
<ul>
```

Now i want to hide items from the last in `menu` and from first in `dd-menu`

Here is my media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    ul.menu li:nth-child(n+2){
        display: none;
    }
    ul.dd-menu li:nth-child(-n+1){
        display: none;
    }    
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    ul.menu li:nth-child(n+3){
        display: none;
    }
    ul.dd-menu li:nth-child(-n+2){
        display: none;
    }    
}
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    ul.menu li:nth-child(n+4){
        display: none;
    }
    ul.dd-menu li:nth-child(-n+3){
        display: none;
    }    
}
@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
    ul.menu li:nth-child(n+5){
        display: none;
    }
    ul.dd-menu li:nth-child(-n+4){
        display: none;
    }    
}
```

but when in mobile device, i can see first item from `ul.menu` and only last item from `ul.dd-menu`

Comment: Do you have metadata for viewport set? Without that your `@media` will not work.

Comment: metadata for viewport?

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Have you considered that the amount of pixels in your mobile device is actually more than 700px?\

Comment: mine is 500px.but here first item from `menu` and last 4 items from `dd-menu` shoud be shown.But only 2 is showing -_-

Comment: yes viewport metadata exists @Justinas

Comment: Should there be a space between `ul.menu` and `li` in `ul.menuli:nth-child(n+2)` ?

Comment: It was mistaken but fixing really does not work.Here @media query in 480px brings 900px first https://www.dropbox.com/s/rij5fznh1f7pix2/Screenshot_12.png?dl=0

Comment: Here is the jsfillde https://jsfiddle.net/4m5dL9g3/ @Rounin

Answer (score 0):

It works now

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    ul.menu li:nth-child(n+2){
        display: none;
    }
    ul.dd-menu li:nth-child(-n+1){
        display: none;
    }    
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    ul.menu li:nth-child(n+3){
        display: none;
    }
    ul.dd-menu li:nth-child(-n+2){
        display: none;
    }    
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 990px) {
    ul.menu li:nth-child(n+4){
        display: none;
    }
    ul.dd-menu li:nth-child(-n+3){
        display: none;
    }    
}
@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
    ul.menu li:nth-child(n+5){
        display: none;
    }
    ul.dd-menu li:nth-child(-n+4){
        display: none;
    }    
}
```

Here is fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/4m5dL9g3/1/

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: It working between min-width and max-width but not only with max-width